# How to generate an executable jar from an Eclipse plug-in project via command prompt?

Tags: java, command-line, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have created an Eclipse plug-in project and able to create deployable jar using in-built Export wizard: 
Export>Plug-in Development>Deployable plug-ins and fragments

Can we automate above workflow using some commands to generate executable jar?

Summary: Is there any way to create executable jar via command prompt?

Comment: You use maven with Eclipse tycho

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to create a plug-in JAR via command prompt:

- Most widespread and in the meantime also used by Eclipse itself: [**Eclipse Tycho**](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho), a set of Maven plug-ins
- Good old [**PDE Build**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/User_Guide#PDE_Build): previously used by Eclipse but still contained in the Eclipse [Plug-in Development Environment](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/)
- ...